# How to get key 'errors' of this data type in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have data type like below. But I want to get the 'errors' key and 'errors.message' value.

```
[  
   {  
      "payout_item_id":"HIDDEN",
      "transaction_id":"HIDDEN",
      "transaction_status":"UNCLAIMED",
      "payout_item_fee":{  
         "currency":"USD",
         "value":"10.25"
      },
      "payout_batch_id":"HIDDEN",
      "payout_item":{  
         "amount":{  
            "currency":"USD",
            "value":"10.00"
         },
         "note":"Thanks for your patronage",
         "receiver":"HIDDEN@gmail.com",
         "recipient_type":"EMAIL",
         "sender_item_id":"1510369638"
      },
      "time_processed":"2017-11-11T03:07:26Z",
      "errors":{  
         "name":"RECEIVER_UNCONFIRMED",
         "message":"Receiver is unconfirmed",
         "information_link":"https:\/\/developer.paypal.com\/docs\/api\/payments.payouts-batch\/#errors"
      },
      "links":[  
         {  
            "href":"https:\/\/api.sandbox.paypal.com\/v1\/payments\/payouts-item\/HIDDEN",
            "rel":"item",
            "method":"GET"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

I have tried to store the code in variable ($get_errors) and then call 'errors' key like this. but the code is not working.

```
return $get_errors['errors']; 
return $get_errors->errors;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to convert your JSON data to array then fetch the desired result from the array Try the following maybe it's work for you

```
$getError = '[  
   {  
      "payout_item_id":"HIDDEN",
      "transaction_id":"HIDDEN",
      "transaction_status":"UNCLAIMED",
      "payout_item_fee":{  
         "currency":"USD",
         "value":"10.25"
      },
      "payout_batch_id":"HIDDEN",
      "payout_item":{  
         "amount":{  
            "currency":"USD",
            "value":"10.00"
         },
         "note":"Thanks for your patronage",
         "receiver":"HIDDEN@gmail.com",
         "recipient_type":"EMAIL",
         "sender_item_id":"1510369638"
      },
      "time_processed":"2017-11-11T03:07:26Z",
      "errors":{  
         "name":"RECEIVER_UNCONFIRMED",
         "message":"Receiver is unconfirmed",
         "information_link":"https:\/\/developer.paypal.com\/docs\/api\/payments.payouts-batch\/#errors"
      },
      "links":[  
         {  
            "href":"https:\/\/api.sandbox.paypal.com\/v1\/payments\/payouts-item\/HIDDEN",
            "rel":"item",
            "method":"GET"
         }
      ]
   }
]';
$array_getError  = json_decode($getError,true);
var_dump($array_getError[0]["errors"]);
```

Comment: if this content is related to your concern then upvote and select as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is Json type. So you have to decode json. Then you can geta data from it

```
$json = '[  
   {  
      "payout_item_id":"HIDDEN",
      "transaction_id":"HIDDEN",
      "transaction_status":"UNCLAIMED",
      "payout_item_fee":{  
         "currency":"USD",
         "value":"10.25"
      },
      "payout_batch_id":"HIDDEN",
      "payout_item":{  
         "amount":{  
            "currency":"USD",
            "value":"10.00"
         },
         "note":"Thanks for your patronage",
         "receiver":"HIDDEN@gmail.com",
         "recipient_type":"EMAIL",
         "sender_item_id":"1510369638"
      },
      "time_processed":"2017-11-11T03:07:26Z",
      "errors":{  
         "name":"RECEIVER_UNCONFIRMED",
         "message":"Receiver is unconfirmed",
         "information_link":"https:\/\/developer.paypal.com\/docs\/api\/payments.payouts-batch\/#errors"
      },
      "links":[  
         {  
            "href":"https:\/\/api.sandbox.paypal.com\/v1\/payments\/payouts-item\/HIDDEN",
            "rel":"item",
            "method":"GET"
         }
      ]
   }
]';

$data = json_decode($json,true);
echo $data[0]['errors']['message'];
```

[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/bAUeS)

Answer (score 0):

```
$x = '[  
   {  
      "payout_item_id":"HIDDEN",
      "transaction_id":"HIDDEN",
      "transaction_status":"UNCLAIMED",
      "payout_item_fee":{  
         "currency":"USD",
         "value":"10.25"
      },
      "payout_batch_id":"HIDDEN",
      "payout_item":{  
         "amount":{  
            "currency":"USD",
            "value":"10.00"
         },
         "note":"Thanks for your patronage",
         "receiver":"HIDDEN@gmail.com",
         "recipient_type":"EMAIL",
         "sender_item_id":"1510369638"
      },
      "time_processed":"2017-11-11T03:07:26Z",
      "errors":{  
         "name":"RECEIVER_UNCONFIRMED",
         "message":"Receiver is unconfirmed",
         "information_link":"https:\/\/developer.paypal.com\/docs\/api\/payments.payouts-batch\/#errors"
      },
      "links":[  
         {  
            "href":"https:\/\/api.sandbox.paypal.com\/v1\/payments\/payouts-item\/HIDDEN",
            "rel":"item",
            "method":"GET"
         }
      ]
   }
]';

$errors = (json_decode($x)[0]->errors);
```

Comment: Hi PSJ, thank your for your comment and it really2 works for me :)